# Permission denied could not read from remote repository

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, git

I am attempting to clone a git repo from inside an ubuntu 20 server, but after it permanently adds my ECSDA key, I get the following error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I do have access to it from my local machine, but how do I access that Github repo from this Ubuntu server?

I tried to clone it by running, `sudo git clone git@github.com:MyRepo/api-service.git`

To to be clear this repository is up on Github and I am inside an ubuntu 20 server trying to clone it.

Is this not a matter of adding the keys from Github?

Comment: Have you tried running the repository clone command in sudo? `sudo su`

`git clone user/reponame`

Comment: @Jeff, yes I get the same error.

Comment: @Nmath, hopefully I added more clarity.

Comment: I have a GitHub account. If you would like to share, I can look at the repo and see if there is another key. I can send it to you and hopefully it will work. My github username is oneenterprisestech or you can ask me questions on my website https://oneenterprisestech.github.io

Comment: This is a Ubuntu Core 20 server?   The 20 indicates a different server product to the far more widely used 20.04 system (ie. 20 != 20.04 with the different format being used for *snap* only 20 products)

Comment: I don't use git often but whenever I've needed to clone a repo, I navigate to the destination folder and simply run `git clone url://` where `url://` is the `.git` URL. Ex: `git clone https://github.com/KDE/krita.git`

Comment: I've never had to use a key to clone a repository before... Have you considered using HTTP or the GitHub CLI option instead?

Comment: @Jeff, I am using SSH.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I meant the other things. I updated the comment.

Comment: Is it a github repo? This is the error you get when trying to clone a private repo (or at least very close to it.) Are you positive the repo owner has access permission set to "public?"

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [Using SSH agent forwarding](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. - From within your Ubuntu server run `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Step 2. - From within your Ubuntu server run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Step 3. - Copy and paste the resulting key and paste it into Github account, by going to **Settings**, then ***SSH and GPG** section and click the **New SSH key** button.

Step 4. - Go back to your Ubuntu server and run `git clone git@github.com:MyGithubRepo/service-api.git`

Comment: OOOOh! I forgot. Git just redid their access restrictions agreement recently. Used to you could just let it prompt you for a password, but giving password via terminal is not allowed on github now, period. You have to set up an ssh key, even if you will only be using it once on that machine...

Comment: Worked for me even if I wasn't able to execute the 4th step

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you should always be able to clone via `https`.

e.g., `git clone https://github.com/mschmidt271/repo.git`

[https clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLanD.png)

If you want to clone via `ssh`, however, you do indeed need to add a key as described in [Daniel](https://askubuntu.com/users/614048/daniel)'s answer. This is due to a recent change in GitHub's `ssh` requirements, as mentioned by [Nate T](https://askubuntu.com/users/1164434/nate-t).